# Van sliding door frozen shut

Tags: toyota, door, winter

I recently purchased a 2004 Toyota Sienna. the winter weather is freezing my sliding doors shut. I dont think it's the locking mechanism  freezing Because that  opens when I push the unlock Button. what can I do to prevent these doors from freezing? I do not have electric doors

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Do you believe it's the seal which is sticking keeping it from opening?

Comment: Confirm you have electric doors (edit your question).  What do you mean theyr'e frozen shut if pressing the button opens them?

Comment: the button will open the lock, but the door will not open when I pull the handle. this happens after a cold night. soon it will be very cold night and day so I must resolve it. I live in Canada. winter is very cold

Comment: Does the handle move easily, then the door sticks, or is it hard to get the handle to unlatch?

Comment: yes the handle moves easily, and the door sticks.

Answer (score 3):

When I had this happen, I cleaned and dried the seals and then sprayed a light coating of a silicone spray on the seals - worked well, but only a light coating is needed.

Edit, I am in Switzerland and although not as cold as Canada, -10 Deg C in winter is enough to give me the same issue as the OP...

Comment: WD-40 works well, too, due to it's water repellent properties. As you say, "light coating" is all that's needed. Good call.

Comment: I will try that

Comment: I'm with the silicone option, but if you can't find silicone lube (a tube versus a spray works just fine as well, apply it with a cotton swab) then Petroleum Jelly works too, it's liquid down to -45C.

Comment: okay thank you, I will go to the hardware store and search for some.

Comment: I purchased some and sprayed one sliding door so I will know if it works. if one freezes and the other doesn't then I will consider it effective. now I'm just waiting for the untreated door to freeze.

Comment: it did not work. van door is frozen shut. its only -11 C° outside

Comment: Is it a solid rubber seal or a”porous” one ie small holes - trapping moisture? Did work for me... and still does...

Comment: it is solid rubber. the other day it wouldn't open for me. I forced it open. bad idea, I knocked it off the track. I did not see any sign that there was moisture on the seal. is possible that there is another reason this is happening .  it does only happen when it's cold. and always both doors are affected.