# van sliding doors frozen shut

Tags: toyota, sienna, van

I have asked this question in the past. followed advice and still  have issue. See [Van sliding door frozen shut](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/60865/10976) I recently purchased a 2004 Toyota Sienna. I do not have electric doors. when it is cold I cannot open my doors. I've tried cleaning the seals and I sprayed it with a silicone based lubricant. the other day it would not open so I forced it open. the door fell off the track, I did fix that. I did not see any sign of moisture on the seals after I forced it open. I'm thinking of buying a car port and leaving my windows open a bit, in hopes that moisture would leave the van. is that a good idea? what are some other potential causes and fixes of this problem?

Comment: See https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/60865/10976

Comment: you are correct I have done everything you have mentioned. you are correct, the slightest freeze locks it. how would I go about removing the locking mechanism.

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=n6ncTH6UO1U you have sprayed the weather stripping with a water repellant and you sprayed the 2 -3 hinges that the door slides on right as well as the groove or track that it follows with a heavier lubricant

Comment: also, I should have mentioned. if I press the unlock Button, the door will unlock. but will not open

Comment: I'm going to throw a guess and say it's the weak spring, it needs to be replaced or soaked. When the door is froze and you get it open does the lock ever stick open

Comment: no I've never had the lock stick open. the van will open after I drive for about an hour. perhaps the heat being on helps.

Comment: I've had the same thing happen, I would prees my door dock, I heard the click when it unlocks just to find out that it did engaged but never released the hook, if I looked crazy enough after several unlock attempts I managed to get it open but then it would freeze in the unlock position lol

Comment: personally I was thinking along the same line as you about it being the locking mechanism